# We take a random sample of $r$ elements of a population of $n$ elements. What is the probability that a fixed element is included in the sample?

Tags: probability

We take a random sample of $r$ elements of a population of $n$ elements. What is the probability that a fixed element is included in the sample?

I don't know how attack this exercise. Can someone help me with that? I don't have an idea on how to approach this.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that it's the first element picked is $1/n$.

The probability that it's the second element picked is $1/n$.

$\vdots$

The probability that it's the $r$th element picked is $1/n$.

Total probability $r/n$.

Comment: Thanks! But one question, what does it mean "element fixed is included in the sample" can you explain me this?

Comment: Simpler than my solution

Answer (score 1):

It means : Probability of having the element at least once in the sample. Which is 1 - the probability of not having the element in the sample.

- with replacement 1-$(\frac{n-1}{n})^r$
- without replacement 1-$(\frac{n-1}{n} \times \frac{n-2}{n-1} ... \frac{n-r-1}{n-r})$